# how to pass a variable from flask to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

The attached pictures are my code where I have enter image description here named as
webapp.py , base.html and template.js file.

In webapp.py ,when passed 'arr' in 'render_template', it does not read in 'creategrid()' function(base.html). the function description is given in template.js. please let me know how
will the passing value to function is will work.
I tried passing values manually in an array then the function works.

Thanks in advance.

[webapp.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO7hS.jpg)

[base.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH1nF.jpg)

[template.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMfFM.jpg)

Comment: can you post the code instead of pictures from your phone of your screen?

Comment: please post the code as a text instead of using images

Comment: sure. I will do.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you haven't initialized the flask app. Before `app@route` add:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

and at the end, add:

```
app.run()
```

Also, you have to call the endpoint `/base` in the url.

Comment: all these are done in the code. I have only posted a part of the code. only when passed through render_template from .py file to creategrid() in .html file, it does not work.